# html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE

Tags: html

html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to include the HTML5 shiv script in order to allow styling of HTML5 elements in older IE browsers: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

To use, include the following script in your  element above your CSS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: shim? shiv? what is going on here?

Comment: @Michael Dillon - technically, it's a shim, but it became known as a the "html5 shiv" after the term was accidentally coined by John Resig (http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, saved my life :)
However, the original code.google source says "for the sake of performance, it would make better sense to include the CSS first then this script"

Answer (score 13):

You need to use [HTML5 Shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/). Here is a [detailed explanation](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/semantics.html#unknown-elements) as to why this is needed.

To use HTML5 Shim, you just need to add the following within your page's `<head>` above all your CSS declarations:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: how about IE 8 and below version??

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which includes the HTML5 Shiv and also provides HTML5 feature detection.

> HTML 5 elements in IE Modernizr runs through a little loop in
>   JavaScript to enable the various elements from HTML5 (as well as abbr)
>   for styling in Internet Explorer. Note that this does not mean it
>   suddenly makes IE support the Audio or Video element, it just means
>   that you can use section instead of div and style them in CSS. you’ll
>   also probably want to set many of these elements to display:block; see
>   the HTML5 Boilerplate CSS for an example. As of Modernizr 1.5, this
>   script is identical to what is used in the popular html5shim/html5shiv
>   library. Both also enable printability of HTML5 elements in IE6-8,
>   though you might want to try out the performance hit if you have over
>   100kb of css.
>
> Supported browsers We support IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.6+, Safari
>   2+, Chrome. On mobile, we support iOS's mobile Safari, Android's
>   WebKit browser, Opera Mobile, Firefox Mobile and whilst we’re still
>   doing more testing we believe we support Blackberry 6+.
>   ~ http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie

The following tags at least: `article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section`

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML5shiv.js or write javascript code in HTML Conditional comments.

```
<!--this condition is only for IE 8 and lesser browsers.-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]> //  means LESS THAN & EQUAL TO IE8. 

<script>
document.createElement('header'); 
document.createElement('nav'); 
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('section'); 
document.createElement('aside'); 
document.createElement('footer');
</script>
<style> 
header, nav, article, section, aside, footer{ display:block; } 
</style>
```

// Now these elements will support in IE8 and lesser browsers.

Or visit this page
https://tutorial.techaltum.com/html4-vs-html5.html

Answer (score 0):

Update - newer versions of IE do support HTML5 structural elements with the exception of the newer 'main' element. Using a CSS reset that includes the 'main' element such as [normalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) will fix this. Or you can just add the following CSS to your project:

```
    main { display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about a little bit code-overhead just use inner DIVs for styling.

This sections can not be styled via CSS with IE<9 (no HTML5-support). 
Even if you put a class-attribute inside the section-tag.

```
<section class="section outer">
    <h1>Level1</h1>
    some text
    <section class="section inner">
        <h1>Level2</h1>
        some more text
    </section>
</section>
```

Thats because IE<9 is killing the nesting for unknown tags.
The DOM looks crazy like this:

```
 <section class="section outer"></section>
 <h1>Level1</h1>
 some text
 <section class="section inner"></section>
 <h1>Level2</h1>
 some more text
 </section><//section>
 </section><//section>
```

But you can use DIVs as an IE<9-Fallback, if you don't like to use javascript shim's.
Instead of styling the SECTIONs, just style the inner DIVs.

```
<section>
    <div class="section outer">
        <h1>Level1</h1>
        some text
        <section>
            <div class="section inner">
                <h1>Level2</h1>
                some more text
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

So you have modern surrounding HTML5-tags for SEO and all the styling is done by the DIVs for every browser as usual. It's full valid HTML5 and still works if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Use the script given below...it will help you..
For each new element you want IE < 9 to recognise..add as below:

> document.createElement("article"); (within script tag) 
> document.createElement("footer"); (within script tag)

Thank you