# header/footer/nav tags - what happens to these in IE7, IE8 and browsers than don't support HTML5?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css, cross-browser

I am eager to start using Html5 in particular the `<header>/<footer>/<article>/<nav>` tags.

What happens if the browser doesn't support these?

Also I need to style these so: For Example: The `nav` has borders and margins etc. You know standard CSS stuff.

So if I style them using the `nav` tag then IE7 & IE8 etc are going to ignore this?

Comment: If you haven't already read [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/), I would heartily encourage you to read it, but for now, I'll answer your question with a link to the [section](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements) describing inconsistencies with HTML5 and IE <9.

Comment: Wow i am just taking a look now! this is great stuff! thanks

Comment: No problem, Martin. Dive into HTML5 is the best resource out there and it's absolutely free.

Comment: It's too bad no answer actually explicitly reveals the truth: you basically have to `<script>document.createElement("article");</script>` for each new element you want IE < 9 to recognise.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie for some solutions.

Answer (score 87):

Place this is the `<head>` section of your page, before any CSS files are loaded.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

html5shi(m|v) creates doc elements for all the html5 elements so the styles from your CSS can kick in. Default behaviour for IE is to ignore unknown elements. For more info see resig's [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/).

Comment: That is useful info Andrew, but you should explain what the code does, to more accurately answer the question and help anyone with the same question.

Comment: been searching for this for a while. thx for posting! this is an amazing script

Comment: Its saves lot of my time @Andrew Tubbs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Year 2016, updated location of html.js: https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js

Answer (score 5):

Yes, IE<9 will ignore any HTML5 elements (reason #3162 no one should ever have used IE) but there are javascript solutions for that which my groggy mind can't think of this morning. I'm sure others will post those solutions below. :)

[First is the html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)