# Nav menu breaks in IE 7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I been trying to fix this for hours i don't know if the css is some how not being applied or what but it only happens in ie 7 / 8. The ie 8 version is almost right but its still messed up can anyone help a chick out ?
http://tshirthideout.com/

here is my code for the nav menu

```
<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

css

```
/* Navigation Menu */
.main-navigation {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}
.main-navigation li {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.857142857rem;
    line-height: 1.42857143;

}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #21759b;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
.menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
            *display: inline
            zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly IE7 and IE8 have largely non-existent support for HTML5. The reality is that if you are writing in HTML5/CSS3 you WILL have headaches getting it to work in IE7/IE8, and that's just the way it is.

To actually begin to solve the problems, check out [HTML5Shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). It provides some styling that helps keep older IEs from utterly failing to understand your HTML5 web page.

Related question: [Html5: header/footer/nav tags etc, what happens to these in IE7,8 and browsers than don't support html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367526/html5-header-footer-nav-tags-etc-what-happens-to-these-in-ie7-8-and-browsers-t)

Try that and then use IE9+s F12 Developer Tools to see what's going on in IE7 - especially check the console, where you'll find a ton of jquery errors in ie7 mode.

If that doesn't work outright, at least it will move the process along to figure out what else is going wrong. But don't worry - all HTML5 pages have this sort of problem.

Comment: ok thank you at least its not just me. I think ill just write a version of the menu for ie 8 and 7 only.

Comment: You're welcome! It's normal to get things working on at least a dozen other varieties of browsers and devices, then find there is a problem with only <ie9. It's...challenging. It'll be that way for the next few years at least, so get use to doing things a few different ways :)

Comment: haha yea tell me about it. i got the ie8 and 7 version of the menu working now.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, couple things.

Try removing the rem units (why do you need those?)

line-height looks like it needs a unit size.

And try updating the `<DOCTYPE>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

And for earlier IE, you may want to change the `<nav>` tag to a `<div>`

Comment: can you give me a example of the line height in units ? i made the other changes. with no effect =(

Comment: "change the <nav> tag to a <div>" idea helped me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)::

> The  tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera,
> Chrome, and Safari.

IE<9 will ignore any HTML5 elements, but there are javascript solutions for that