# My CSS is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I am using PHP and I have one CSS file. Everything is working fine in Mozilla and Chrome but it's not working in IE.

Some CSS like `.Mainheader` nav is not working in IE. How can I manage my page so that it looks same in different screen resolutions?

html:

```
 <header class="mainHeader" > 
<nav>
<ul>
 <li >
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
 <li >
<a href="about_us.php">About Us</a>
</li> 
<li>
<a href="#">How It Works</a>
</li>
 <li>
<a href="contact_us.php">Contact</a>
</li> 
<li>
<a href="register.php">Manufacturer Register</a>
</li> 
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Here is my css code:

```
/* ===========================
   ======= Body style ======== 
   =========================== */

body {
    background-image: url('img/bg.png');
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size: 14px */
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    }

.body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:60%;
}

.divimg{
    margin-left:480px;margin-top:-40px;
}
.divchat{
    margin-left:610px;margin-top:-60px;
}

.reginput
{
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:5px;
}   
    a.one {text-decoration:none}
a.one:link {color:#CF5C3F;}
a.one:visited {color:#CF5C3F}
a.one:active {color:#CF5C3F}
a.one:hover {color:#CF5C3F;background-color:#FFFFFF;}
/* ===========================
   ========= Headings ======== 
   =========================== */
h2 {font-size: 1.571em} /* 22px */
h3 {font-size: 1.429em} /* 20px */
h4 {font-size: 1.286em} /* 18px */
h5 {font-size: 1.143em} /* 16px */
h6 {font-size: 1em}     /* 14px */

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Anchor style ====== 
   =========================== */
a {
    outline: 0;
    }

a img {
    border: 0px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ===========================
   ===== Main Navigation ===== 
   =========================== */

.mainHeader nav {
    background: #666666;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.mainHeader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader img {

    height: auto;
    margin: 1% 0;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Content Area ====== 
   =========================== */

.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    width:750px;
}

.topcontent {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 0% 0%; 
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #FFF; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.content {


    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}

.post-info {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 85%;
}

/* ===========================
   ======== Sidebar ========== 
   =========================== */

.top-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

.btnstyle{
    background-color:#00E6E6;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* ===========================
   ========= Footer ========== 
   =========================== */

.mainFooter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #FFF;    
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 2% auto;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Media Queries ====== 
   =========================== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 1024px)
{
    .body {
        clear: both; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 90%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav {
        background: #666;
        font-size: 1.143em;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader nav ul {
        list-style: none; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li {
        margin-left: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:active,
    .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
        background: #CF5C3F;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li a {
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .mainContent {
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .topcontent {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 0% 0%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
    }

    .bottomcontent {
        background-color: #FFF; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 2% 5%;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }   

    .post-info {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;       
    }

    .top-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .middle-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;   
    }

    .middle-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .mainFooter {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 2% 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        background-color: #666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        color: #FFF;    
    }

    .mainFooter p {
        width: 86%;
        margin: 2% auto;
    }

    .divimg{
    margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;text-align:center;
}
.divchat{
    margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;text-align:center;
}

    .divimg img { max-width: 10%; }
    .divchat img{
    max-width: 30%;
}

.reginput
{
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
}
```

Comment: what you mean than not working?

Comment: create a style sheet for IE and borders does not work in IE 8

Comment: What version of IE?  What is it that isn't displaying correctly?  More details will be required to help with the issue

Comment: php is a unnecessary tag.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: use new version of ie

Comment: i have IE 8 ..this is not working in IE
<header class="mainHeader" >
<nav><ul>
<li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li ><a href="about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
<li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="register.php">Manufacturer Register</a></li>
</ul></nav></header>

Comment: Please reduce this to a specific, reproducible problem, and explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: <header class="mainHeader" > 
<nav><ul> <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
</ul></nav></header> 
this is not working

Comment: @akash That's an entirely unreasonable suggestion. The OP has no control over what the site's users browse with.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support HTML5 tags like `<nav>`.

Comment: ok,so what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of IE you are using? IE have less support for HTML 5. Kindly read the below questions, may be these will help you:

[header/footer/nav tags - what happens to these in IE7, IE8 and browsers than don't support HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367526/html5-header-footer-nav-tags-etc-what-happens-to-these-in-ie7-8-and-browsers-t)

[html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie)

and also this

http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/

Comment: so try <div.. instead of <header...

Comment: Then read http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/ , it has no support for NAV and other HTML 5 tags , so it will not work in IE 8 .

Comment: and <div class="nav"> instead of <nav>

Comment: ok sir i'll try,and how can i manage with defferent screen resolution

Comment: managing different resolution is a huge topic. I think you should try to use some css / js framework like twitter bootstrap  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html , which also provide support support for responsive layouts. It has only two main files, css file, js file and about two images, but it is very good and you will be free to worry about browser supports, even IE 7 :) .

Answer (score 1):

To add to altafhussain's answer, take a look at ie-7.js / ie-9.js too.

https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

It's a small Javascript which you can embed (look at the docs on the linked page). It automatically makes IE7 and IE8 support the HTML5 tags like ,  and . It also allows to use eg :before and :after pseudo classes

Comment: what about nonjs users?

Comment: Personally I don't support nonjs IE-users. If someone chooses to still use IE7 or IE8 AND turns off their JS, they are dead to me ;)

But if you do want to support them, I'd recommend using <div> tags instead of html5 tags (eg <div id="header"> instead of <header>)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its the same like that from intval, but here is another way to help IE 8 to understand HTML5:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

[Google Code HTML5 for IE](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)