# Relative-layout, Mobile version not displaying properly.. HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Unusual problem and i just cant figure out why its happening, basically ive tried viewing the site via responsinator
 and it all seems fine, when resizing the browser it seems fine too (even at mobile size) but when viewing the site on an iphone it seems to not have listened to the media query at all..

http://jsfiddle.net/z5jVJ/

when validating the entire css i get the following

```
Parse Error
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 85%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav #pull {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 5px !important;
    left: 5px !important;
}

nav ul {  
    display: none;  
    height: auto;  
}  

nav a#pull {  
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: -3px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;  
    width: 90%;  
}  

nav a#pull:after {  
    background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;   
    height: 1px; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;  
    right: 15px;  
}

#mainHeader nav {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

#mainHeader nav ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#mainHeader nav ul li a {
    padding: 0px;
}

#mainHeader nav a:hover {
    color: #dfdfdf;
}

#mainHeader ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 53px;
}

#mainHeader nav ul li a {
    padding: 0px 0px;
}

.banner .label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;    
}

.banner .category {
    text-align: right;
    min-width: 96.5%;   

}

#mainContent { 
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

#mainContent img {
    width: 96.5%;
}

.article {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -9999px !important;
    left: -9999px !important;   
}

#footer { 
    height: 50px;
}
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend _not_ using the <nav> tag as it is not supported in IE<9. Instead use divs and ul's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367526/html5-header-footer-nav-tags-etc-what-happens-to-these-in-ie7-8-and-browsers-t

Comment: What did you define your viewport as?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" /> thats the viewport, and i just removed the nav tags and changed the css up but still no luck

Comment: Try changing your viewport to this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @msbodetti still no change.. this is one of those pulling your hair out problems cause everything seems fine

Comment: haha yea @box maybe try change the media query to this ...media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)

Comment: @msbodetti yes! finally it works aha, how did you come to this solution if i may ask for future reference?

Comment: I realised from the above you said "when validating the entire css i get the following" But there's a Parse Error, so I thought okay well the media query might be the issue. Check out this page http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/ I bookmarked it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! bookmarked too, validated the css now and its error free, leave it as an answer and ill accept it :)

Comment: Added it as an answer, thanks for suggesting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your media query, there's a "Parse Error" after you validated your CSS.

So change this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

To this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```