# IE8 display inline-block issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

For some reason, IE-8 doesn't display my menu inline. (see picture attached)
My code is:

```
#navigation #main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I have found the following post [IE8 display inline-block not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working). Tried adding the Doctype, as well as added this code:

```
<!-- [if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
  #navigation #main-menu {
  display: inline;
  }
</style>   
<![endif]-->
```

Still doesn't work, any advice? you can see a picture with the issue here: http://preciseos.com/PreciseOs/Untitled.jpg

Here is the html code:

```
<ul style="margin-top:20px;margin-right: 10%;" class="nav-collapse collapse" id="main-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#page-welcome">Home</a></li>                                              
    <li class=""><a href="#page-about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-features">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-work">Work</a></li>                       
    <li><a href="#page-contact">Contact</a></li>
```

You can also see the issue at www.preciseos.com.

Thanks,
Oz

Comment: A little html and more css would be great, since now it's not clear which element exactly is the #main-menu, and what's going inside of it.

Comment: Inside the CSS if condition put: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`. Does it help?

Comment: Thank you, I have added some HTML code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> why dont you add htis??

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Why dont you add this?? which is the answer of your source. Give it try

IE8 will treat it as a block level element unless you use float

**Note:**

I posted doctype as comment but it was corrupted, so posting this  as answer

**Updated:**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li class="actives"><a href="#page-welcome">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li class="actives"><a href="#page-about">About</a>

    </li>
    <li class="actives"><a href="#page-features">Services</a>

    </li>
    <li class="actives"><a href="#page-work">Work</a>

    </li>
    <li class="actives"><a href="#page-contact">Contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 .actives {
     display: inline;
    padding:10px;
     float: left;
 }
 a {
     text-decoration:none;
 }
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xZwq7/10/)***

Answer (score 1):

The reason it breaks the layout is `IE8` does'nt support HTML5 Elements such as `nav`.

Instead you can use `<div>` tag or try including javascript Workaround **[HTML5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)** to support `IE`

Comment: He doesn't use HTML5, there's no element in his html called nav

Comment: @OzPorat Please try some fix I suggested and let me know

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you target the `li` element with your selector

```
#navigation #main-menu li
```

as well try using `float` instead of `display: inline;`

```
#navigation #main-menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Surjith SM said, the IE8 doesn't support HTML5 elements such as nav.
The problem was solved by adding the following code:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

html5shi(m|v) creates doc elements for all the html5 elements so the styles from your CSS can kick in. Default behaviour for IE is to ignore unknown elements. For more info see [header/footer/nav tags - what happens to these in IE7, IE8 and browsers than don't support HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367526/header-footer-nav-tags-what-happens-to-these-in-ie7-ie8-and-browsers-than-don)