# My css is not working in IE browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Guys my `CSS` is not working on `IE` browser. In `Chrome` and `Firefox` it is working fine, but in `IE` its not applying single style. If you have any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Some of css is not working in IE old versions. So you need to use `--webkit` to support css in IE browser

eg.

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#d5cea6+0,c9c190+40,b7ad70+100;Brown+3D */
background: #d5cea6; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%, #c9c190 40%, #b7ad70 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d5cea6', endColorstr='#b7ad70',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

**Here Add this for background gradient to support IE**

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d5cea6 0%,#c9c190 40%,#b7ad70 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d5cea6', endColorstr='#b7ad70',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother... which version of IE you are using? IE doesnt support for HTML 5 that much. Kindly go through the below links, may be these will help you:

[header/footer/nav tags - what happens to these in IE7, IE8 and browsers than don't support HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367526/header-footer-nav-tags-what-happens-to-these-in-ie7-ie8-and-browsers-than-don)

[html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie)

and also this

http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/