# JavaScript not running on IE7 & 8 with no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to make [thecourtyardstanmer.co.uk](http://thecourtyardstanmer.co.uk) work in IE7 and IE8 but I am having trouble as there are no console errors at all.

Could there be a reason JavaScript would not function but display nothing in console?

I have tried looking for trailing commas in objects and arrays as I know IE hates this but cant find any.

**EDIT:**

The one thing I do get in console is `[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector` which is wrong as there *are* elements in the cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Comment: Do you have script debugging enabled in the IE options?

Comment: @Steve there was some messages in the console, so I presume yes. But no errors. Where can I check?

Comment: In the menu : Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced

Comment: If you hit F12, the developer console should also appear but i don't know if you have to have script debugging enabled too.

Comment: I have enabled them and it made no difference, i have been using the F12 dev tools to look at console.

Comment: I had a look at the site in IETester and the only possible problems I can see are some sort of CSS problem where the navigation menu is going off the screen - is that what the problem is? It doesnt look like a javascript problem...

Comment: Try this as it looks like your header is HTML5 which is causing a problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @Steve An hour ago the website looked *very* messed up in IETester lol, I have put in the shim that Simon West suggested and it seemed to have fixed the problem, although for a while i didnt think it was fixed as doing a refresh in IETester was still showing me the same broken website, after restarting the program it now displays fine and i have fixed the offset menu issue you mention above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector` is being written (twice) to the console. and is being generated by the jQuery cycle plugin.

It could all be caused by your use of new HTML5 semantic markup but i cant see any kind of [HTML5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) in order for these elements to render correctly in older version of IE, if they dont render properly it could be completly screwing the DOM structure causing your selectors to fail

Comment: Thanks, I have put the shiv in, and it seems to have made a big difference in IE7 but none in IE8. I think you are along the right lines as both cycle plugins *do* have elements in them

Comment: @Jleagle Checking your website now youve added the shiv im not seeing anymore console messages and it behaves identically in IE8 and IE9 now and functions in IE7 (although the top navigation menu needs some styling adjustments). N

Comment: Thanks, IETester was playing up on me and not refreshing correctly, so didnt realise it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cycle-plugin-cycle-terminating-zero-elements-found-by-selector