# DIV (footer) not being pushed down after toggle on IE

Tags: jquery, css, html

This works fine on FF and IE9 but fails in IE7 and 8.

I have two hidden divs that contain a form inside. Once you click a button the correct div with the form will show below. All of this works fine but in IE7 and 8 the footer will overlap the form and won't be pushed down by the toggle event.

Here is my html (reduced):

```
    <div class="row" id="contactesp">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <!-- Contact Form 7 plugin shows the form here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="contactmund">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <!-- Contact Form 7 plugin shows the form here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer role="contentinfo" id="content-info">
        <div class="row">Content here</div>
    </footer>
```

My CSS (some of it):

```
 #content-info {
     background-color: #1C3F94;
     clear: both;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     float: none;
     margin: 20px -20px 0;
     padding: 0 4%;
     display:block;
 }
 #contactesp, #contactmund {
     display: none;
     height: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

I also added overflow:hidden in the form but to no avail.
Here is my JQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.enesp').on('click',function(){
            $('#contactmund').hide();
            $('#contactesp').toggle();
        });
        $('.enmund').on('click',function(){
            $('#contactesp').hide();
            $('#contactmund').toggle();
        });
    });
```

The site is here for the complete code: http://www.institutoespanol.net/contacto/ and the problem shows up when you click on either of the buttons within the maps boxes.

Comment: remove clear:both and float:none from #content-info

Comment: @SACHIN you should discuss here rather than asking him to send the code or better jsfiddle

Comment: ya i knw but when i am checking on ie webdeveloper tool and removing the float and clear then its working fine in my system

Comment: Maybe this link helps you in you reflexion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie this script create the missing element of html5 for Internet Explorer like footer.

Comment: @CharlesJourdan I'm already using it in the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set *position: relative* to the **< footer >** tag. The overlap problem will get solve.

```
footer{ position:relative; }
```

Comment: Add the above mentioned style either your ie.css (for less than 9 browsers) or foundation.css (common css)

Comment: I tried this and though it's not showing in the IE developer tools it is there and there's no effect

Comment: Nevermind the last comment this did the trick. Why Is the position relative needed?

Comment: "zoom:1" style is the problem in IE browsers layout. Please refer [The Power Of ZOOM - Fixing CSS Issues In Internet Explorer](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm) to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do a restructure of your html in the following manner,

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <div class="main-page">
            <!-- All the main content here, all the divs as you want put it at this place. -->
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <!-- Footer contents -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and assign this css

```
.main-page {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

Probably this will help. This structure has removed some of my `ie` errors.

As another point of note please check [this link](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) for coding a sticky footer. This is more or less the same concept of dealing with the structure of your html page.

Comment: This website does not use a sticky footer, if I do this the layout will not be consistent with the design in other pages

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/qUESn/1/