# <nav> tag, supported by all browsers?

Tags: css, html, nav, navigationbar

I've found [this tutorial, that uses a `<nav>` tag](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly). the demo works well even on IE7.
and yet, [w3cshools mention that this tag is NOT supported on IE8 and below](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) .

So, what's the truth and should I keep this nav tag, or change it to a div? (would it ruin anything?)

Comment: First, do not trust w3schools.

Comment: Check [HTML5 Semantic Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) indeed, never read from w3schools. Simply put, `<nav>` tag was introduced after IE7-8 were developed or standardised, nor will older versions IE will attempt to update to new standards.

Comment: @MackieeE that's a good answer, go for it :)

Comment: +1 enapupe http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `HTML5 shiv script` in order to allow styling of HTML5 elements in older IE browsers: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

To use, include the following script in your element above your CSS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

See -> [html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie)

Another option is to use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), which includes the HTML5 Shiv and also provides HTML5 feature detection.

Comment: how does the demo I've mentioned works on my IE10 with a IE7 console then? is it not really a 100% IE7 simulator?

Comment: You should include the HTML5 shiv script and you are ok. Don't trust W3Schools so much...

Comment: @rockyraw I believe as IE10 sits on a different rendering engine, I wouldn't **trust** the emulation, despite that it says it can; but in my experience, sitting at a WinXP machine with IE7 feels and behaves differently from IE10 trying to act like it (Mind you, that's an opinionated answer, without fact)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, why would one trouble himself with including extra scripts, if it's possible to simply change `<nav>` to `<div>`?

Comment: One of the new elements for HTML 5 is the <nav> element which allows you to group together links, resulting in more semantic markup and extra structure which may help screenreaders.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use div instead but the point of using nav is to get rid of a div.

Don't waste your time trying to get HTML5 to work in old browsers.

Comment: this does makes more sense, why would one trouble himself with including extra scripts, if it's possible to simply change `<nav>` to `<div>`, can anyone explain?