# What versions of IE supported by bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

> From [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/): Specifically, we support the latest versions of the following browsers and platforms. On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11. More specific support information is provided below.

But I tested my site in almost all latest browsers that displaying fine. But when I tested it on Internet Explorer it's display is showing as if it is mobile view(as we use col-xs-*:: all contents are displayed as this view).

- In IE11 -- it's fine.
- In IE10 -- it's fine.
- In IE9 -- it's displaying as if it is mobile view
- In IE8 -- it's displaying redundantly

[image]

So, as said does bootstrap really supports IE8 , and IE9?

---

I'm using bootstrap 3.1.1 and testing my site on windows.

Comment: put  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> on your head section, and it will work fine in ie9 and ie8

Answer (score 5):

IE versions 8 and newer are supported. The following meta tag is required to prevent IE from entering 'compatibility mode', which emulates IE7. (This is most likely why your site has issues with IE9.)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

---

IE8 fails to support the following: `border-radius`, `box-shadow`, `transform`, `transition`, and `placeholder`.

IE9 fails to support `transform` and `transition`.

Comment: Thank for your great answer. But still not fine even after placing meta!

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Are you using the IE8/IE9 Browser mode and Document mode in the dev tools? Sometimes these still work differently than the real thing. You may want to check out http://modern.ie.

Comment: I tested in ie8 real browser too!

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Are you using the `<nav>` element? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: oh yes I'm using html5 elements.

Comment: Try adding the [HTML5 Shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), and including it before any css/js, and after the meta tag.

Comment: I did but same problem again nothing changes. I also tried other methods as you provided other so q/a

Comment: oh! I notice the issue was coming because I'm using column count css.